# Shrinking NTFS partitition for SSD Migration

Tags: windows, hard-drive, windows-10, partitioning, ssd

Goal: Migrate Windows 10 from 500GB spinner (hard disk drive) to 240GB SSD.

[Procedure indicates partition not exceed SSD capacity.](http://www.howtogeek.com/97242/how-to-migrate-windows-7-to-a-solid-state-drive/)  In this case ~200GB.

[Windows Disk Management Console procedure enabled me to shrink it to 235.1 GB](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/windows-vista/resize-a-partition-for-free-in-windows-vista/) with 90% free space. Is there another utility that can overcome the obstacles that Windows Disk Management Console can not overcome?

I realize that 240GB capacity labels are typically less actual usable space, but are the number reported in the disk management labels number and not usable space?

Update: Good news: I was able to use Apricorn's EZGIG to clone the 235.1GB partition to the target 240GB drive. – gatorback just now

Answer (score 1):

What you need is probably a data migration software that also does on-the-fly defragmentation (i.e. moves data from the rear end of the disk to the front part, so it all will fit on the SSD–assuming there is enough free space).

Simple data-to-data copy will not yield in a bootable disk, as you need to take care of disk signatures/partition offsets or, in case of (U)EFI, the Unique identifiers of the Disk and the partitions.

A software like [HDClone](https://www.miray-software.com/products/applications/hdclone.html) would do that for you, but the free edition won’t copy to a smaller disk, so you might have to look for alternatives.

Answer (score 1):

Using Gparted for this can be very dangerous, as it's not highly aware of NTFS data mappings (relies on the NTFS3g driver set), and can easily cause corruption while shrinking an FS to be "very small".

You need to defragment your filesystem and consolidate free space. The Windows defragmentation tool should do this fine, though you can use most any other third party tool. The reason you can't shrink anymore is because you're running into an area mapped by the $MFT that has data, so it won't shrink past that to avoid corruption.

Defragment / consolidate, THEN shrink.

Answer (score 0):

Use a GParted (http://gparted.sourceforge.net/download.php). You can turn the ISO file into a bootable thumb drive with UNetbootin (https://unetbootin.github.io/)